# SCORM Quizzes from Office

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, scorm

Does anyone know of MS Office (Word, Excel or PowerPoint) templates for create a SCORM quiz? Paid or free, but must be customizable in VSTO or VBA. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at [PowerSCORM](http://powerscorm.codeplex.com/) which is in PowerPoint VBA.